# Numbers that are clearly NOT a Square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial, square-numbers, conjectures

Although I have never studied math very seriously, I have heard of [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem), which asks for integer solutions for the following Diophantine Equation:$$n!+1=m^2$$

The only solutions are conjectured to be $(4,5),(5,11),(7,71)$, and there are no solutions for $n < 10^{9}$.

However, it is clear there are an infinite amount of $n$ where it is simple to verify $n!+1$ is not a square.

For example, take $n=81$. Assume that $81!+1$ is a square.

This implies that $81!-1=a^2-2$ for some integer $a$.

Note that by [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), $82!\equiv -1 \pmod {83}$, implying $81! \equiv 1 \pmod {83}$.

Thus, $a^2-2 \equiv 0 \pmod {83}$. A contradiction, since $2$ is not a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) of $83$.

In a similar way, we can claim that for all $n>5$ where $n+2$ is a prime number $p$ such that $ p \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$, then $n!+1$ is not a square.

My question is, are there any other integers $n$ where it is simple to verify $n!+1$ is not a square? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks! I appreciate that you like my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your nice argument can be generalized.

For example, take $n=80$. You deduced from Wilson's Theorem that $81!\equiv 1\pmod {83}$. Now $$80!\equiv \frac{1}{81}\equiv -\frac{1}{2}\pmod{83}.$$ Here $\frac{1}{2}$ means the inverse of $2$ modulo $83$. It follows that $80!+1\equiv -\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{1}{2}\pmod{ 83}$. Because $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $83$, neither is its inverse, so $80!+1$ cannot be a square. Of course, this works for any $n$ for which $n+3$ is prime congruent to $3$ or $5$ modulo $8$.

More generally, for any prime $p$ and positive integer $k\leq p-1$,
$$
(p-k)!+1\equiv \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!}+1=\frac{(k-1)! \big[(k-1)!+(-1)^k\big]}{((k-1)!)^2}\mod p.
$$
So $(p-k)!+1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $(k-1)! \big[(k-1)!+(-1)^k\big]$ is a quadratic residue. Via quadratic reciprocity this can be translated to a condition on $p$.

For each $k\geq 1$, there is a condition similar to yours. I'll list the first three (they start looking complicated very fast). The quantity $n!+1$ cannot be a square if any of the following conditions hold:

- $n+2$ is a prime congruent to $3$ or $5$ mod $8$
- $n+3$ is a prime congruent to $3$ or $5$ mod $8$
- $n+4$ is a prime  congruent to $5$, $9$, $21$, $23$, $31$, $37$, $43$, $45$, $49$, $51$, $55$, $57$, $59$, $65$, $67$, $69$, $71$, $73$, 
  $77$, $81$, $83$, $85$, $87$, $91$, $95$, $97$, $99$, $101$, $103$, $109$, $111$, $113$, $117$, $119$, $123$, $125$, $131$, $137$, $145$, $147$, $159$, or $163$ mod $168$.

The primes in the third case are exactly those for which $42$ is a quadratic non-residue.

Comment: Nice. Was this known/discussed before? When I first thought of this I wondered if this could make testing if $n!+1$ is a square easier, but seems to be that that seems difficult.

Comment: I don't know (+ a few characters to reach to minimum comment length)

Answer (score 0):

In fact testing that $n!+1=m^2$ is reduced to solving the following quadratic equation:
$n!=k(k+2)$ with $(k+2)=2*T_{i}$ with $T_{i}$ a triangular number.

A simple way to see that is to look at the multiplication table to see:
$4!=1*2*3*4= 4*6=4*(4+2)$. Note that $4,6$ are on parallel diagonals to the main diagonal of squares and on a line that passes between two squares. A similar relation exists between odd numbers (like $3*(3+2)=15=4^2-1$ and $5*(5+2)=35=6^2-1$...)

In general we have:
$4*6=5^2-1$
$10*12=11^2-1$
$18*20=19^2-1$
...
$70*72=71^2 -1$, the one corresponding to $7!+1=71^2$.

However, besides the known solutions with $4,5,7$, no other solution of $n+1=m^2$ has been found. But it's easy to find out if any given $n!$ can be put into the form $n+1=m^2$ by solving the quadratic equation $k^2+2k-n!=0$.

For more details, see this:
[Is this formulation of the Brocard problem better suited to tackle the problem of solving $n! + 1 =m^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697074/is-this-formulation-of-the-brocard-problem-better-suited-to-tackle-the-problem-o)